# STM32F4 USART USB communication with PC?

Tags: usb, stm32

I am trying to use STM32 provided example of USART called "HyperLink" which basically runs USART1 on ports PA9 and PA10.

The problem is that my computer does not find any new COM ports.

Do I need any additional drivers or anything else?

PS. I am connecting my USB to CN5 and LD7 goes high, indicating that VBUS is present.

EDIT: Code used

```
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
  USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;

  /* Enable GPIO clock */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

//  RCC_AHB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB2Periph_OTG_FS, ENABLE);

  /* Enable UART clock */
  RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE);

  /* Connect PXx to USARTx_Tx*/
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_USART1);

  /* Connect PXx to USARTx_Rx*/
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_USART1);

  /* Configure USART Tx as alternate function  */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Configure USART Rx as alternate function  */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 115200;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;

  /* USART configuration */
  USART_Init(USART1, &USART_InitStructure);

  /* Enable USART */
  USART_Cmd(USART1, ENABLE);
```

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. There are many areas where your setup could be failing. The easiest litmus test is whether or not your computer makes the 'du-duh!' sound when you connect your device (i.e. the same sound that comes when you plug in a USB stick). If yes then you need to install a driver. If not then your STM32 isn't emulating a COM device.

Comment: Much more information is going to be needed here in order to be able to provide support. Only a few readers are will likely recognize the terms PA9, PA10, CN5 and LD7. A diagram showing the connectivity would also be useful.

Comment: tmwoods, computer does not recognize COM device. Could it be the problem on STM32 side or PC side?
Please request any necessary information and I will try to deliver.

Comment: The USB controller on the STM32 needs to pull the pullup high so that the host detects it and requests the relevant information for enumeration. Are you running the ST USB stack to handle this?

Comment: I have attached the code I am using and it seems it is pulling up the pins.

Comment: I see UART initialisation, but no USB init.

Comment: I guess it's no as easy as I thought it would be...

Comment: Exactly. You have to have an interrupt service routine that will handle SETUP and OUT/IN packets that come in. You don't have thathere.

Comment: What if I don't want my computer to interpret STM32 as proper USB, but just as serial COM?

Comment: You don't need USB init at all, USART alone should be fine. But there are still so many fault points that it is difficult to begin. First off you need to determine if your computer is recognizing your device. Go to Device Manager and see if a COM device is added when you plug in and if so, does it have a recognized driver. And switch to [Termite](http://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm). It's a much better terminal program.

Comment: Also when responding say '@tmwoods' so that way the user will be notified there is a response waiting for them.

Comment: @tmwoods thank you for helping me. My computer does not recognize COM device in Device Manager. It does not show any virtual ports. That's the main concern.

Comment: In that case this is a very difficult problem to assess with the information you have provided, or even with more information. To start, where did you get this code? Was it from a sample program or library? Maybe give a little history as to how you got here and we can start with that.

Comment: @tmwoods here is the origin of the code: http://coocox.org/show_exam/USART/456.html

Comment: Everything seems in order, but you may have to debug it a little. And where do you call this code? Do you have a main program anywhere? One that enables interrupts and attempts to send a character?

Comment: I guess even if I didn't send character, my computer would recognize this Virutal COM?

Comment: It should still recognize it yes. But right now you have a nice piece of code written here; I just want to make sure you are calling it somewhere. I mean is this a section of your main? Or is this embedded in a custom function? My question is how are you calling this code?

Comment: @tmwoods this code is in a method which is called in main(). Do you have stm32? You could try if the code works for you.

Comment: I do not have an STM32. Did you enable global interrupts in your main()? If that isn't the problem then I am not sure what would be without going through each command and the datasheet to make sure it is done correctly.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I think I would like to see your code calling this from your main if it is possible.

Comment: @tmwoods as I mentioned, I am just calling Usart_Printf(); function in main(); And no, no solution yet...

Comment: You have to enable global interrupts usually. Can you post your main() code? Because I think that will be the problem and how you call it.

Comment: I have the exact problem as the OP. I have installed Virtual Com Port Drivers from STMicroelectronics. Yet, my device manager doesn't detect any serial port when the CN5 USB port is connected to my computer. LD7 is turned on.